# Modeling calculated value in OWL

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, modeling, owl, ontology

I am currently working on a OWL model for corporate finance, and some important values are calculated through one or more model. My problem is to model this fact. Basically, I have a `Company` class (with some descriptors as `Turnover`, `Number of sales`, etc., modeled as data properties) and I would like to add values like `Working Capital`.

Should I add a `Calculated measure` class, and link it to my `Company class` (which seems weird because classical descriptors are data properties)? I think there should be a better way to model that.

Comment: What exactly do you want to represent?  If you had properties "hasAs" and "hasBs", then you could certainly create a property "hasTotalAsAndBs" and you could store the sum of the two values there.  If you do that, it would be good to add an rdfs:comment to the property stating that its value is the sum of the others.  If you actually want to *compute* the value, then you'd probably want to use a SWRL rule to compute it.  Some OWL reasoners support SWRL rules, and you can store the rules in the ontology.

Comment: Do you mean that there is more than one way to determine Working Capital -- so you want to say "Working Capital according to this model" in one case and "Working Capital according to that model" in another?

Comment: Actually, I am in the case described by Phil. For the moment, I have created a class "Indicator" and a child class "Working capital". This child class has child classes itself "Working capital model A", "Working capital model B"… And I have created an Object Property between company and working capital "has Working capital". But I am not sure if this is the best way to do the trick.